# How to write query to retrieve latest time value closest to today in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to retrieve latest value for each card from time from the table in SQL including sensor id and event type closest to todays date please?

```
create table events (
    sensor_id integer not null,
    event_type integer not null,
    value integer not null,
    time timestamp unique not null
);
```

I have tried code below

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM events
WHERE events.time < "2021-01-01 00:00:01"
ORDER BY events.time DESC
```

Top 1 does not work in mysql and limit 1 did not get me the results.

I need to get latest time value for each sensor_id not only the latest value for the whole table.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are basically asking us to either design, or design and write code from a Specification. 
That is not what StackOverflow is for, we help each other fix code related issues we are having, we dont write code for you

Comment: ok, sorry, let me figure it out an I will share it with you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `order by` and `limit`.  Let me assume that you mean *on or before* today:

```
select e.*
from events e
where e.timestamp <= now()
order by e.timestamp desc
limit 1;
```

If you want future dates as well, this can be tweaked.